# Why i can't login to code-server on my Debian VM?

Tags: linux, xcode, authentication, debian

I have successfully installed code-server on a VM instance of Google Cloud, when i access from mi browser, code-server asks me to login, it says that the password is in `~/.config/code-server/config.yaml` so when i run: `sudo cat ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml` i copy the password and put into the textbox, but when i try to login, it say's me: "Incorrect password".

I've tried to change the passtowrd in the config.yaml file and restart code-server but it didn't work.

I've got the latest version of code-server:

https://github.com/cdr/code-server/releases/download/3.4.1/code-server-3.4.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz

My VM is running over Debian GNU/Linux 8.9 (jessie)

I jus wrote the command: `sudo wget https://github.com/cdr/code-server/releases/download/3.4.1/code-server-3.4.1-linux-amd64.tar.gz`

So i've extracted all files with the `tar` command, and i've moved all the files of the folder to my Debian bin directory.

I'm running this command to execute code-server: `sudo code-server --bind-addr=0.0.0.0:8080` and i'm accessing code server through: `mydomain.com:8080`

So i don't know what is happening, could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that i was executing the `cat` command through my own user on the server, but code-server was taking the info from the root user of the server, i've solved changing to the root user: `sudo su -` and executing the `sudo cat ~/.config/code-server/config.yaml` command again, it gaves me the right password of code-server.